# Syncfusion PDF Conversion Limit

Tags: winforms, pdf-generation, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion for Windows form and converting my data through **GridPdfConvertor** Class.
This Class works fine for upto 100,000 records But when my records exceed then its Gave me the GDI+ error.
So please tell me about the limitation of **GridPdfConvertor** Class.
Is there is a limitation exist or not ????

Answer (score 1):

Usually while converting the data more than 100,000 records will throw exception. You can say that this is the limitation for converting the records. You can overcome this by exporting the grid to PDF using the `ExportToPdfWithMerge`.

This will export the grid into multiple parts and ensure its combination into a single document at the final. So it can export more rows than normal export.

```
// C#
pdfConverter.ExportToPdfWithMerge("Sample1.pdf", this.gridControl1);
```